# How to prevent preview from recognizing the numbers in PDFs as phone numbers?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, ocr

As a tech worker, I often read documents in PDF formats, and Preview often recognize the numerical parameter sets in those documents as "phone contacts".

How do I prevent Preview from doing so, so that it'll be less likely to butt-dial random people that I don't know?

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you could clarify whether you're using a mobile (iOS) device or macOS.

On macOS, there would be a preference that could change this. It is working in applications like TextEdit but as of yet not in Preview.

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit "DataDetectors" '0'
```

What you could do for now is either use a different PDF Reader or disable FaceTime on your macOS.

I have the same issue with Preview and submitted [Feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).